# How do you do a string split with 2 chars counts in C#?

Tags: c#, string, split

I know how to do a string split if there's a letter, number, that I want to replace.

But how could I do a `string.Split()` by 2 `char` counts without replacing any existing letters, number, etc...?

**Example:**

```
string MAC = "00122345"
```

I want that string to output: 00:12:23:45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```cs
string newStr= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(MAC, ".{2}", "$0:");
```

To trim the last colon, you can use something like this.

```cs
    newStr.TrimEnd(':');
```

[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_String_TrimEnd_System_Char___)

Comment: Your Code result is "00 12 23 45". If you change "$0 " to "$0:" - it returns  "00:12:23:45:" but the required answer is  "00:12:23:45"

Comment: Thanks @NitikaChopra I was thinking OP can fix that .LOL. Updated the answer anyway.

Comment: I didn't do that .. I don't know who downvote your answer. In fact, I helped you with your answer

Comment: I didn't say to you @NitikaChopra, I was asking the one who did it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208751/discussion-between-nitika-chopra-and-manjuboyz).

Comment: it adds the colon at the last string.

00:12:23:45:

Comment: you can use TrimEnd(':'); for that string, that should work.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I think that a regex is not a good solution for something like this. It's very inefficient. more or less 15x slower than my answer...

Comment: Since MAC is already a string, and strings are immutable, you can omit the Convert.ToString() operation on MAC.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a LINQ extension method to give you an [`IEnumerable<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8) of parts:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitNthParts(this string source, int partSize)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("String cannot be null or empty.", nameof(source));
        }

        if (partSize < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Part size has to be greater than zero.", nameof(partSize));
        }

        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, (source.Length + partSize - 1) / partSize)
            .Select(pos => source
                .Substring(pos * partSize, 
                    Math.Min(partSize, source.Length - pos * partSize)));
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var strings = new string[] { 
    "00122345", 
    "001223453" 
};

foreach (var str in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", str.SplitNthParts(2)));
}
// 00:12:23:45
// 00:12:23:45:3
```

**Explanation:**

- Use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) to get number of positions to slice string. In this case its the `length of the string + chunk size - 1`, since we need to get a big enough range to also fit leftover chunk sizes.
- [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) each position of slicing and get the `startIndex` using [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) using the position multiplied by 2 to move down the string every 2 characters. You will have to use [`Math.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.8) to calculate the smallest size leftover size if the string doesn't have enough characters to fit another chunk. You can calculate this by the `length of the string - current position * chunk size`.
- [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) the final result with `":"`.

You could also replace the LINQ query with [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) here to increase performance for larger strings since all the substrings won't be stored in memory at once:

```
for (var pos = 0; pos < source.Length; pos += partSize)
{
    yield return source.Substring(pos, Math.Min(partSize, source.Length - pos));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
    string MAC = "00122345";
    MAC = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(MAC,".{2}", "$0:");
    MAC = MAC.Substring(0,MAC.Length-1);
    Console.WriteLine(MAC);
```

Comment: that only display 00:12.

Comment: Nope. Just try out in this fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/oINy5Q

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand and simple solution.

This is a simple fast modified answer in which you can easily change the split `char`.

- This answer also checks if the number is `even` or `odd` , to make the suitable `string.Split()`.

---

> *input : 00122345*
>
> *output : 00:12:23:45*

---

> *input : 0012234*
>
> *output : 00:12:23:4*

---

```
//The List that keeps the pairs
List<string> MACList = new List<string>();

//Split the even number into pairs
for (int i = 1; i <= MAC.Length; i++)
{               
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        MACList.Add(MAC.Substring(i - 2, 2));
    }
}

//Make the preferable output
string output = "";
for (int j = 0; j < MACList.Count; j++)
{
    output = output + MACList[j] + ":";
}

//Checks if the input string is even number or odd number
if (MAC.Length % 2 == 0)
{
    output = output.Trim(output.Last());
}
else
{
    output += MAC.Last();
}

//input : 00122345
//output : 00:12:23:45

//input : 0012234
//output : 00:12:23:4
```

Answer (score 0):

A quite fast solution, 8-10x faster than the current accepted answer (regex solution) and 3-4x faster than the LINQ solution

```
public static string Format(this string s, string separator, int length)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += length)
    {
        sb.Append(s.Substring(i, Math.Min(s.Length - i, length)));
        if (i < s.Length - length)
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
string result = "12345678".Format(":", 2);
```

Comment: Faster maybe, but also better? How should this be used, seeing this question on SO ?

Comment: @Luuk I just added an example

Comment: CS0176 Member 'string.Format(string, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead .

Comment: If not in the same namespace, you must add a `using` to import the extension method

Comment: I created [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6AIJ5k) just to check if this was really faster, but .... can you calirfy on the error and how to solve  (line#24)?

Comment: Move the static extension method in a static class, for example `public static class Extension` https://dotnetfiddle.net/YwPNmO. Use Stopwatch instead of DateTime, should be tested in Release mode and not Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one (1) line alternative using [LINQ Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8).

```
string result = MAC.Aggregate("", (acc, c) => acc.Length % 3 == 0 ? acc += c : acc += c + ":").TrimEnd(':');
```

Comment: And if performance really is a concern, this is the second fastest solution, only slightly slower than Bidou. You get performance and ease of development ;)

Keep in mind, premature optimization can kill productivity.